# why Class not Found

Tags: php, laravel

I can't solve this problem.
I pushing ctrl  and clicked `use App\ParentModel;` 
Move to ParentModel right.

ExactError is this.

```
.ERROR: Class 'App\Model\ParentModel' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0):
 Class 'App\\Model\\ParentModel' not found at C:...laravel\\app\\Model\\ViewModel\\ChildModel.php:9
```

FileTree

```
App
|
Model
|
-------- TableModel ---- ParentModel.php
---------ViewModel  ---- ChildModel.php
```

what's wrong .
please give me advice.

ChildModel.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Model\ParentModel;

class ChildModel extends ParentModel   <---- Class ParentModel not found!
{
  public static function getData()
  {
    return ..
  }
}
```

ParentModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ParentModel extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;

  public function aaa()
  {
    return ..
  }
}
```

Comment: Your parent model is in TableModel directory?

Comment: fix `namespace` it will work

Comment: @Mohammad Hosseini yes

Comment: You should edit your name spaces and ```use ModelNames```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Based on your

```
App
|
Model
|
-------- TableModel ---- ParentModel.php
---------ViewModel  ---- ChildModel.php
```

this is solution

in `ParentModel.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Model; // add this

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ParentModel extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;

  public function aaa()
  {
    return ..
  }
}
```

in `ChildModel.php`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Model\ParentModel; <---- add correct path

class ChildModel extends ParentModel   
{
  public static function getData()
  {
    return ..
  }
}
```